# UploadStringAsync don't call callback

Tags: c#

I've searched a while but i only see solution that suggest to use httpclient, i'm unfortunately sticked to webClient and i'm wondering why this is not working.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var uri = new Uri("MY_SERVER_URL");

        string username = "xxx";
        string password = "xxx";
        string uriParam = "username="
                         + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(username)
                         + "&password="
                         + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(password)
                         + "&client=myClient";

        var client = new WebClient();

        client.UploadStringCompleted += GetProfilesCompleted;
        client.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        client.UploadStringAsync(uri, "POST", uriParam);
    }

    static void GetProfilesCompleted(object sender, UploadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Error);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: looks like there is a fair chance that your program finishes before the WebClient gets its response. Add `Thread.Sleep(1000)` at the end of main method, this should help. Also, switch to HttpClient, with which you can await the calls

Comment: did you look here in the 2nd option? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26167133/webclient-uploadstringcompleted-event-not-being-called

Comment: Solved, Krzysztof Skowronek had to wait before parsing the result

Comment: That is a misuse of Thread.Sleep. What if it sometimes takes longer? You should simply prevent `main` from exiting, the simplest way is to use `Console.ReadKey();`